# When I press enter I get isNaN, but the value is a number

Tags: javascript

This is a problem that I don't understand because all the code validates. It's my homework that's due tonight at Midnight.

When I enter a value into the 'Price' text box and hit enter I get the $isNaN in the 'Total' textbox. Any suggestions. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4       /loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Price Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixOrder()
{
  var numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value);
  var taxP = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value);
  //var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);

  if (isNaN(numPrice)){  
    alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
    if (isNaN(taxP))
      alert("Sorry, you must enter a numeric tax value to continue");
  }

  var tax = (numPrice * taxP)/100;
  var total = numPrice + tax;
  document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#00f3F1">

<h1 align="left">Price Calculator</h1>

<form name="form">
<p>
  Price:  <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="fixOrder();"/>
</p>
<p>
Tax: &nbsp; <input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" onchange="fixOrder();"/>
</p>
<p>
  Total: <input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled();"/>
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read up on using javascript debuggers. Look into Firebug for Firefox or the debug tools in Chrome. IE9 also has decent developer tools. That makes solving problems like this a lot easier. Here is a little tutorial on Chrome's debugger. http://www.alexatnet.com/content/sample-debug-session-google-chrome-javascript-debuger

Comment: As long as I am adding tips - check out jsLint. It detects syntax errors in your code. For example, visit this fiddle and click the jsLint button at the top. It would have caught this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/MVG5q/

Comment: I cut and pasted into W3schools tryit editor, and it works fine. I think I agree that you need to learn a debugging tool, however.

Comment: you need to put a green check mark next the post that you think is the answer.

Comment: press F12 on Chrome browser to bring up the console , where you can enter javascript expressions for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4       /loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Price Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isNumber(value) { 
    return typeof value === 'number' &&
            isFinite(value);
}

function fixOrder()
{
    document.getElementById("total").value = "";  // clear the total field
    var numPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cost").value);
    var taxP = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tax").value);
    //var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);

    if (isNaN(numPrice)) { 
        alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
        return;  // exit function to avoid calculation
    }
    if (isNaN(taxP)) {
        alert("Sorry, you must enter a numeric tax value to continue");
        return;  // exit function to avoid calculation
    }

    var tax = (numPrice * taxP)/100;
    var total = numPrice + tax;
    document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);

 }

 </script>

 </head>

 <body bgcolor="#00f3F1">


<h1 align="left">Price Calculator</h1>

<form name="form">
<p>
Price:  <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="" onchange="fixOrder();"/>
</p>
<p>
Tax: &nbsp;
<input type="text" id="tax" name="tax" value="" onchange="fixOrder();"/>
</p>
<p>
Total: 
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" value="" disabled="disabled"/>
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the isNumber() function is not used . But you can use it to test if a value is a number in future .

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to close your `{` and `}`, and you should `return` to avoid calculating.

```
if (isNaN(numPrice)) { 
    alert("Sorry,you must enter a numeric value to place order");
    return;
}

if (isNaN(taxP)) {
    alert("Sorry, you must enter a numeric tax value to continue");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. See, I learning something I hadn't seen in the text book. This course I'm taking is online. So I encouraged to go online to find answers. And I'm getting them.

Answer (score 0):

disabled="disabled();" may be a problem- make it read only, and the tax as well.

You can figure the tax and the total from the price.

Your code is reading an empty value (NaN) the first time you change either input.

You don't need names and don't give form elements the same identifiers as the variables in their own handlers- they are globals in some browsers..

Comment: disabled="disabled"  will do .

Comment: My instruction from the professor was to use disable="disabled" The code is working a lot better now. After entering a value in the first field, I entered a value in the tax field and bingo I got the results in the total field. Man, am I happy.